# upgrade fedora from 29 to 30

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I wanna update fedora from 29 to 30 and I used regular commands to update fedora that u can find them in fedoramagazine or other websites listed in google. but I have got an error after I entered:

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

and fedora answered:

```
Error: system is not ready for upgrade
```

I can not find anything related to this error. system is not ready!!!

is there any suggestion or related experience?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try below sequence(Remember to take backup if something you need)

```
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=30
sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

Comment: Error: system is not ready for upgrade

Comment: Even after following above steps, if not stop all the services so only upgrade can run over internet.

Comment: Try replacing the third command with: `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=30 --allowerasing`